# Is there any way to reject unwanted inputs in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm making a simple batch script that has 4 options--4 different things built into it. It accepts 1, 2, 3, and 4. Only issue is, if the user inputs anything *other* than that, it defaults to 1. Which I do not want. I'm tired and my Googling hasn't been that sharp--what I'm asking is if there's a way to check if the input for %op% (variable in use) is not equal to 1, 2, 3, or 4. And if it is not one of those; tell the user to try again. Code snippet is attached:

```
:check_Permissions
    echo Did you run the script as admin?
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
    net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        echo Script run as administrator, continuing.
        timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
        goto options
    ) else (
        timeout /t 1 /nobreak > NUL
        echo Please re-run the script as an admin. Press any key to exit.
        pause>nul
        exit
    )

:options
echo.
echo ==================================
echo 1. (First option)
echo 2. (Second option)
echo 3. (Third option)
echo 4. (Fourth option)*
echo *: (Note to fourth option)
echo.
echo Please pick one of the options.
echo ==================================
set /p op=Selection: 
if "%op%"=="1" goto lorem
if "%op%"=="2" goto ipsum
if "%op%"=="3" goto dolor
if "%op%"=="4" goto sit
```

Comment: If the user didn't enter `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`, none of those `if` statements will get triggered. Since scripts flow from the top down, what can you do after those `if` statements to make the user enter a value again?

Comment: `CHOICE` seems like a better option: `choice /N /C 1234`

Comment: I mean...there's not much left for input after that. I dont know if I'm understanding right but I can't have the entire thing go from top to bottom with no interaction as all of the options would break each other if ran after another.

Comment: Will look into choice, thanks. Some of this was cross referenced from ancient stackoverflow posts anyway; which is probably not the best.

Comment: There's a `goto` command where you can go to a specific label, like `:options`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a label (try_again) and an extra line in the if-conditions block. Something like this:

```
if %op%==1 goto lorem
if %op%==2 goto ipsum
if %op%==3 goto dolor
if %op%==4 goto sit
goto try_again

:try_again
cls
echo Please try again!
pause
goto options
```